# Help in drawing confidence ellipse

Tags: r, confidence-interval, multivariate-analysis

car packages's [ellipse function](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/car/html/Ellipses.html) asks for a `radius` parameter. In help says that is the "radius of circle generating the ellipse". Could you please tell me which circle is this?

Thank you very much

Comment: I think that if the ellipsoid is of the form $(x-\bar{x})^TS^{-1}(x-\bar{x})=g^2$, then g should be given as radius.

Comment: George is correct.

Answer (score 4):

An ellipse can be parametrized as the affine image of any given circle. If we consider the unit circle:

$$x=a \cos (t)$$
$$y=b \sin (t)$$

```
ellipse(center, shape, radius, log="", center.pch=19, center.cex=1.5, 
  segments=51, add=TRUE, xlab="", ylab="", 
   col=palette()[2], lwd=2, fill=FALSE, fill.alpha=0.3, grid=TRUE, ...)
```

You can notice the `ellipse` function asks for the center and the radius of the circle, as well as the covariance matrix, which is equivalent to giving the parameters of the affine transformation.

```
center  2-element vector with coordinates of center of ellipse.
shape   2 * 2 shape (or covariance) matrix.
radius  radius of circle generating the ellipse.
```

Let us have a look at the `car` package function:

```
ellipse <- t(center + radius * t(unit.circle %*% chol(shape)))
```

The `radius` parameter can be set to 1 if you want to use the covariance matrix directly for the `shape` parameter. I believe it was introduced to help people use normalized matrices instead if they prefer so.

---

Edit: As mentioned in whuber's comment, the two ellipses below are the same.

```
> library(car)
> s=matrix(c(1,0,0,1), nrow=2, ncol=2)
> plot(0, 0, xlim=c(-5,5), ylim=c(-5,5))
> ellipse(c(0,0), 4*s, 1)
> ellipse(c(0,0), s, 2)
```

Comment: Actually, the affine transformation from the unit circle to the ellipse is given by the *square root* of the "shape" parameter.  E.g., the matrix {{4,0}, {0,4}} will only double the size of the circle.